# ADB Connection via Mobile Hotspot

Tags: adb, samsung, wifi-hotspot

How can I connect my phone to my Mac via ADB while using my Mac that is connected to the phone's hotspot?

The port is already open on 5555, on a normal WiFi connection I can just connect via the IP that's shown in the WiFi Settings

I've tried connecting to the IP that ifconfig gives me but the connection remains unauthorized and no Popup got on my phone

Comment: *the connection remains unauthorized* - if you're seeing this than fix this problem in isolation. Connect device to Mac using USB cable and authorize Mac in the dialog shown in the device. Now switch to hotspot, get the phone's IP address for hotspot network and connect to it using adb. The default gateway provided by hotspot to your Mac is the IP address of your phone. Connect to that and share your observation here.